# Fascia Wrap and Boards

Tags: roof, roofing, fascia

[image]I've been told I need to have fascia wrap removed to inspect and replace any damaged fascia boards. Then new fascia wrap would be installed. Is that difficult or impossible to do without having to remove or disturb installed drip edge, or risking damage to the roof? I'm trying to figure out if I should take care of fascia wrap/boards before considering replacing the roof. Is this a service many roofers are willing to do in your experience?

Answer (score 1):

If the fascias are just needed to be inspected, are there signs showing potential issues like discoloration at the joints as if water was getting in behind the wrap and rotting the material underneath?

I guess that question could have been left in the comments but to address your concerns, most of the fascia covering I seen that were installed and the ones I installed are done after the roof edging and roof is installed. All the nails/screws holding it should be accessible. Some may be placed under the lip of the drip edge, but they can be removed the same as they went in, by gently raising the edge and with the proper nail puller, remove them and the fascia.

Most certainly pop rivets are involved, and hopefully sealant too at the folds of corners. Those are drilled out with an 1/8" drill bit.

Most facia when installed does not need a lot of nails. The bottom edge in many cases is held in place by the way it is bent to go around the base material at the bottom. The top only needs 2 fasteners to keep it in place, since it is, or should be tucked under the drip edge, so no water can get in from the top. Most water gets in from the vertical joints that are not lapped enough or corners that are not folded properly and/or not sealed. The only other way moisture will get in is by condensation, which is uncontrollable, that is why weep holes are made in the bottom edge if the fascia is bent like a "J". Some facias are bent like an "L", this type will not trap condensation or any other water infiltration, but need to be riveted at the bottom in a few places to keep it intact.

The reason the material only needs a few fasteners is, it is a very rigid material. The bends at the bottom will keep it straight. The top edge is kept straight by the drip edge that covers it, although it may deflect a bit under it, but is usually covered by a gutter on the drip edge, not so on the rakes. If many fasteners are used, the metal and in some cases vinyl, will expand and buckle between the fasteners, making it look unsightly. This can be avoided by using a slot cutter to make elongated holes for nailing, so the metal can move as needed while expanding and contracting.

Comment: I've no drip edge. I plan to re-roof house too. The top 1-2" of fascia wrap is flared out, with  top edge wrap same height as l top edge of fascia board but ~1" gap between them. Have you ever seen such?  It'd require a longer, undesirable drip edge to span the gap to avoid dumping water into gap, and there would be a >1" horizontal extension of drip edge and shingle overlap which could allow water and wind to blow under shingles. Per GAF, drip edge should be installed first under underlayment and WeatherWatch ice & water shield.

Comment: I read if roof & fascia are replaced at same time, first roof edge shingles are installed, then fascia is replaced. Why can't fascia work be first, or can it? Then when house is reroofed a less unsightly, more durable, protective drip edge suitable for the straight style fascia wrap and gutter position could be installed. It'd eliminate the possibility of a roofer needing to disturb/remove recently installed drip edge, new I&W shield & underlayment to replace fascia which would then mean retrofitting drip edge so it'd not be under I&W/underlayment which could void warranties and is not ideal.

Comment: One roofer said if he were replacing roof,  he'd have to cut down wrap ~1" to remove flared top around entire perimeter to install drip edge. Usual drip edge would drop water into the gap, so was not an option, but he said longer drip edge would run into top edge of wrap because wrap is same height as board but 1" away. My understanding is drip edge is made to, and needs to, slope down a bit so it would hit inside top of wrap. Could roof be done first, and then if needed have roof edge tarped to prevent normal size drip edge dumping water into gap until fascia boards/wrap could be replaced?

Comment: By the way - thanks for your first response, which gave some good information. Besides questions above, do you think J-shaped or L -shaped fascia wrap would be best?

Comment: I prefer the J type, to me it looks proper. That is only an esthetic preference. The way the wood fascia is profiled, along with how the soffit (the underside of the overhang) is installed, if it has a finished soffit, will dictate the style of fascia to use. I do not understand about the one roofer cutting the 1" of the facia (wrap) nor how the top is flared out in your first comment. I have seen fascia with 2 opposing 90 degree bends at the top to mimic a "rake mold" but that needs material behind it to aid in it's securing in place  ___,----- To the left I attempted to "draw" the edge (cont

Comment: with dashes, a comma and underscores to get the idea across. Normally when a roof goes on, even though the bottom edge where the fascia is where the roof starts, the way fascia is covered at the top by a drip edge, holding the top tight to its backing/nailer, when the roof is started the gravel surface of the shingle come with a lot of loose gravel that readily falls off. That will get trapped behind the fascia and make it bulge out in places. The drip edge, sometimes has the same problem, depending on when the roofing felt is placed. Before or after the drip edge. This is a big problem (cont)

Comment: removing old roofing. I have experienced this myself., when the drip edge is removed too. It would help if you could get a picture of what you have, otherwise I would perhaps do a lot of unneeded speculation. The comments about the drip edge and I&W shield are a given, drip edge first, I&W shield after, fascia next. I guess the fascia could be done first since the I&W shield will seal everything up from gravel intrusion. Sorry about the back and forth, I had to give the whole picture some thought.

Comment: I added picture. I was told there is an ~1" empty space gap between top edge of fascia wrap and top edge of fascia board.

Comment: That helps, I can see the J style working there. The detail at the top, on my end looks like a shadow line, I can't make out the profile, but it does suggest the profile I was thinking, unless the face of the material just makes a tight bend and goes at an angle, instead of turning out 90 degrees for a short bit and turns 90 degrees again to go to the underside of the shingles.  Since there is no drip edge, the fascia may bend back at the roof level and attaches to the top of the roof, and the nails are covered by the shingles. If that is so, it is a very good situation, to keep in place.

Comment: My impression from what roofers communicated is that it doesn't bend back, but just flares out - with one bend - at ~45 degrees for the top 2-3". The picture shows rake edge. I just read people, even me, often use the wrong term fascia boards vs. rake boards. Do you know what contractors call what's shown in picture?  Would it be "rake wrap" or "rake molding"?  If an estimate gives a cost per LF for replacement of fascia wrap, would that probably include replacement of "rake wrap"? Total LF not listed so I can't tell.

Comment: Terminology can vary a bit from region to region, so I have seen, moving from the east coast to the west coast. As far as I know, they are all generically called fascias. They can further be determined by rake boards, the angled ones, and the level ones, the eaves. Eaves may be the whole "overhang" : the fascia, including the soffit. This may depend on the region.  About the rake mold, the 45 degree part of the rake, I am curious how it is controlled at the top, I have not seen a rake done like that. They are usually closed or backed/filled in and nailed so it does not move uncontrolled.